# Publishing android app update with lower API support

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the Play store that works fine on API18 and below but not on devices running KitKat+ (Due to the [default sms app requirements for API19+](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)).

I am trying to allow only compatible (API18 and below) devices be able to download my app.

**What I've done so far...**

1. I have built against SDK18
2. My manifest file sets
   `<uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="14"
       android:maxSdkVersion="18"
       android:targetSdkVersion="18" />`

**The problem**

When I upload the signed APK to play store I get the following error

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>   It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 14-18 to API levels in range 19+ should downgrade from version 14 to version 12, which would occur when 
>   Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
>   Features containing all of [android.hardware.TELEPHONY, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.WIFI].

Removing the maxSdkVersion allows me to upload the APK without error.

My understanding (best guess) is because maxSdkVersion is deprecated. I also understand the existence of some sort of connundrum because existing users with API19+ who try and update will be faced with an APK that says "dont allow API19+"

**What I need help with**

My app filters sms based on certain factors and allows/blocks from the inbox. Since this is not longer possible at the moment, I need to exclude API19+ so users stop complaining that "your app doesn't work". Where am I supposed to be looking.

Thanks all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about publishing on Google Play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no way to do this, unfortunately. Your best bet is to simply check if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19` and then displaying an error message in the app itself explaining  that it is not supported on the device.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much.